# Store class delegate and call a particular function

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to make a piece of code which will store a class reference and is able to call a particular function inside of it. This would mean I can swap out the class to achieve different functionality. So for instance, I can have a class instance hold

```
     classDelegate cl = new ofSomeClass();
     cl.executeFunction("functionName");
```

In other words, I can initialize one class which calculates 1+1 and then another which calculates 2+2. This way I can dynamically swap out the calculation, simply passing a different class to inialize cl with.

This is a pain to explain... hopefully I made some sense... is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you posted is somewhat vague, but it sounds like you need to define an interface and then have each of the differen classes implement that interface.  In your example, where you're referencing a "calculate" method, you would just define an interface like this:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int NumberOne
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    int NumberTwo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    int Calculate ( );
}
```

Then when you create your different classes, they would implement the interface like this:

```
public class TwoPlusTwoCalculator : ICalculator
{
    private int _numberOne;

    private int _numberTwo;

    public int NumberOne
    {
        get
        {
            return this._numberOne;
        }
        set
        {
            this._numberOne = value;
        }
    }

    public int NumberTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._numberTwo;
        }
        set
        {
            this._numberTwo = value;
        }
    }

    public TwoPlusTwoCalculator ( )
    { }

    public TwoPlusTwoCalculator ( int numOne, int numTwo )
    {
        this.NumberOne = numOne;
        this.NumberTwo = numTwo;
    }

    public int Calculate ( )
    {
        return this.NumberOne + this.NumberTwo;
    }
}
```

Then in your code when you want to invoke the Calculate method you can cast an instance of the TwoPlusTwoCalculator, or OnePlusOneCalculator, or any other class that implements the interface as that interface:

public void GetValue ( int numOne, int numTwo )
        {            TwoPlusTwoCalculator calculator = new TwoPlusTwoCalculator ( numOne, numTwo );
            PerformCalculation ( calculator as ICalculator );
        }

```
    public int PerformCalculation ( ICalculator calculator )
    {
        return calculator.Calculate ( );
    }
```

Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Possible... Also not exactly clear what you want to do:

If you are trying to call method by name - use reflection - [`GetMethod(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)

You aslo can have multiple classes implemeting an interface:

```
  interface MyFunctions{
     void ExecuteFunction(string name);
  }
```

Or use derived classes with common base class (similar to interface):

```
public abstract class MyFunctionBase {
   abstract void ExecuteFunction(string name);
}
```

Or simply use `Action` class:

```
 Action myFunc = ()=> 1+1;
 myFunc();
```